# Save text area to file

Tags: java, file-io, textarea, save

Is It possible to save a textarea to a file?

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(txtArea1);
```

I get:

> txtArea1 cannot be resolved to a variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We can't really help you based on just that, no. We have no idea what `txtArea1` is, where it's declared, where this code is, or even what UI framework you're using. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`JTextComponent.write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29).

> Stores the contents of the model into the given stream. By default this will store the model as plain text.

Thus, your example might look something like:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
txtArea1.write(fw);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it:

```
JTextArea txtArea1 = new JTextArea();
```

Then, when you save it, save `txtArea1.getText();`

Comment: If this was the solution, I would **highly** recommend learning Java in the first place. I refuse to believe you wrote what was in the OP and then not know what that error message means...

Comment: Is this high recommendation for me?

Answer (score 0):

I see only very few reasons to save a plain text GUI component to a file. If you only need to save the content, it is better to store the content string that can be obtained through `getText()`.

However it may be that you need to store some settings that can be done on `JTextArea` (tab size, etc). For that, I would propose to use [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html):

```
   XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(
                      new BufferedOutputStream(
                          new FileOutputStream("save.xml")));
   e.writeObject(txtArea1));
   e.close();
```

This will save all non default settings as well as the content string. It is also possible with serialization but this format is less portable between different virtual machines.